# Call method from parent class after call method from child class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor, automated-tests

I have Parent class and Child class extended by Parent class.
Parent class is a menu displayed on each page of application - so it is extended by all Child classes in app.

I try do to sth like this:
1. Call method from Parent class which return Child class 
2. Do some action on Child class (SearchPage)
3. Navigate to other Page (child) by use Parent class

On step 3 I get error. I think this is related to circular dependency but I cant find any workaroun.  I cannot find solution for this.

```
 E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kamil/Projects/automatedmt/tmp/LearnerApp/pages/SearchPage.js:19:36)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kamil/Projects/automatedmt/tmp/LearnerApp/LEPPage.js:3:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

[14:52:27] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

Comment: Are you calling "super()" from the child class to invoke the constructor in the parent class?

Comment: Some code to see the problem you're describing would be 

Comment: @nowy Please look at my before question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206739/fluent-interface-with-protractor-and-typescript

Comment: I know why you get this error, will answer tomorrow. You should do composition over inheritance in a few words.

Comment: @Oleksii I'm waiting for your answer :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312197/node-js-v6-2-0-class-extends-is-not-a-function-error/37312355#37312355 take a look at it

Comment: if you have `index` file, try to delete `export` for `SearchPage`

Comment: @Oleksii thanx for link, but I'm not really know how to do this in my case. Can you show it to me on my code? What do you mean index file?

Comment: It's hard because I don't see entire repo. Workaround is removing inheritance. Add Parent class for each page via composition. You are right about a circular dependency.

Comment: Tell me please if you don't understand how to make it via composition.

Comment: @Oleksii exactly, I completly dont't know how to use it, I would be grateful if you can show me how I shoul do it on my example code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206739/fluent-interface-with-protractor-and-typescript

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to judge the error based on what you've provided.

I'm assuming it's due to you missing `super()` in the child constructor. `super()` is used to invoke the constructor in the parent class and pass through the relevant services, parameters, etc to the parent.

**parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { 
    super(http)
  }   
}
```

Comment: Sorry for spam, but on my before question no one answered so I tryed to  describe it easier. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206739/fluent-interface-with-protractor-and-typescript